# How can I implement a match or if statement based on an enum's current value in Python?

Tags: python, enums

I have the following enum defined in some Python code:

```
from enum import Enum

class TestEnum(Enum):
    MY_VALUE=1
```

I want to implement a `__repr__` function for this enum.

- Actually, it doesn't have to be `__repr__` this is just for convenience when using `str()` conversion

```
class TestEnum(Enum):

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        match self:
          case TestEnum.MY_VALUE:
              return 'my_value'
          case _:
              return 'INVALID'

test_enum = TestEnum.MY_VALUE
print(str(test_enum))
```

- The idea of using `match self:` comes from Rust. It may not be valid syntax in Python.

This code outputs the following:

```
TestEnum.MY_VALUE
```

Which is not what I was hoping for.

Can what I am trying to achieve be achieved with Python?

Comment: `str` -> `__str__`, `__repr__` -> `repr` - it's only `str` -> `__repr__` if `__str__` isn't implemented, per https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__. `repr(TestEnum.MY_VALUE)` **is** `'my_value'` (if I combine the two snippets into an actual [mre]) and (if I add another member such that `case _` is actually reachable) every other member's representation **is** `'INVALID'`.

Comment: Yep, the base `Enum` class's implementation of `__str__` is independent of its `__repr__`: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/ffac6ac656f5ba591cddc88c990c2187a4d9a83d/Lib/enum.py#L1219

Comment: Just replace `__repr__` with `__str__`. Then it will do exactly what you're asking it to do (i.e. convert to a string).

Comment: There is no benefit in using match-case in this code. If-else would be be simpler and more efficient. Match-Case is best reserved as intended for structural pattern matching not to replicate a basic switch.

Comment: @user19077881 That makes no sense to me. `if-else` and `match-case` do the same thing. Why should `if-else` be either simpler or more efficient?

Comment: @user19077881 So - what is your point? I hope it's not that match is slower for two reasons: 1. Did you measure it and if so is it notably different? 2. Why would you care about the performance of code written in Python? Put another way: Let's assume a match statement is 10x slower than an if statement in Python. Does that matter? No - unless it is part of a hot loop. If it is part of a hot loop, how much does the overall performance change by removing it? Probably not noticiably. If it is noticable, Python is the wrong tool for the job.